# Подмена штатной камеры на usb-камеру

Tags: android, usb, skype, web-камера

Есть ли возможность внесения изменений в настройки ОС Андроид таким образом, что бы подключенная через usb веб-камера воспринималась аппаратом в качестве штатной? Что бы приложения, которые работают только со штатными камерами также работали и с подключенной через usb?

Поясню, почему такая задача передо мной встала:
Использую в командировках планшет, для рабочих скайп-совещаний. Камера на планшете разбилась. Подключил к камере, через usb, внешнюю веб-камеру, но skype имеет возможность выбора камеры только из числа штатных: фронтальную или тыловую. С юсб камерой работают другие приложения, но мне необходимо что бы именно в skype, где все мои рабочие контакты, определялась веб-камера, взамен сломанной фронтальной.

P.S. да, я куплю новый планшет :) но мне просто стала интересна данная задача. Казалось бы решение лежит на поверхности, но не все так просто... Пожалуйста, подскажите, в какую сторону направить поиски решения?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю здесь можно обойтись без внесения изменений в настройки ОС Андроид. Во время разговора по скайпу включите трансляцию с экрана и зайдите в приложение которое работает с внешней веб камерой (у Вас на экране будет изображение с камеры, а у собеседника на экране будет виден Ваш экран).